# Javascript - Hide source files from chrome console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, parceljs

I'm kinda new to Javascript development myself. Lately, I've been working on a web app using React and ExpressJS. Express will deliver the static bundled(using Parcel) files of front-end React page. The code organisation is something like this:

```
> dist\    
>     [static files here] 
> node_modules \ 
> src \
>     client\
>        compontents\       
>        index.html
>        index.js
>     server\
>       models\
>       routes\
>       index.js
```

The build process works fine and I get a perfectly working web app. The problem is that Google Chrome's Source developer tool exposes all of my source code for the client.
[Exposed source code files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrWBo.png)

Some googling led me to terms such as blackboxing and obfuscation. But I have a hard time understanding them. Some explanation of them and advice on hiding source files will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot hide any file that's getting loaded on any page. Browser need it to run your website. Obfuscation is making your code harder to read essentially modifying your meaningful variable name like `username` to `a`.

Comment: But this seems to expose all of node_modules! Including the packages' source code!

Comment: Your browser needs the source code of each library in order to run them. If there are third-party libraries that you don't need at runtime, consider putting them under `devDependencies` in your `package.json`

Answer (score 3):

Finally got it.
I had to include --no-source-maps in parcel build command

```
parcel build ./src/client/index.html --no-source-maps
```

Comment: care to elaborate please? what is the output of this? Does this help your cause hiding data from `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set the following option, your react source code (not minimized) will be visible.
You need to turn off the GENERATE_SOURCEMAP flag.

in package.json

"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
  ...
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically a web browser need to download your .js files in order to work. You cannot prevent this. However, in the published react project, the js files are minified so you dont need to worry about exposing your source code.

Comment: Yes I understand! Isn't the transpiled react code located at dist\ folder and delivering them alone is enough?  I am perfectly fine exposing code post-bundling, but this seems to be exposing all of my source code! Including all of node_modules!

Comment: Dont know what is your Chrome settings, but my browser only shows the complied js files that relevant to the project, i.e. component---xxxxx.js, app-xxxxxx.js. Can you check for other websites that are using react and view their source code to see if you can see similar structure folders like yours?

Comment: This is not compiled code. It is at best minified and uglified, but in the end, it's the exact same code. Nothing is hidden, but just harder to read.

Comment: @ArnaudChrist not exactly complied, but still not just minified and uglified, i.e. your project is huge but in the end, the app-xxx.js is the final result along with the components are packed into one file

Comment: True, single bundle which usually is the minified and uglified concatenation of all your project's files. But agree with you, this can be seen as a compilation phase. But I thought it was useful here to add some precision on the fact that the final code is not compiled in the sense that it is hiding the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can blackbox your web app by using a service like [HideJS](https://hidejs.herokuapp.com) to create an interactive stream of your site, instead of actually compiling the code on their end.

The code never reaches their computer, so it's not possible to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the name .env in your project folder with the below code inside it:

GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

Now run    command from the terminal, It will generate a  folder with minified files.

Answer (score -3):

### It is not really possible to completely block inspect element on your website. But you can block some popular ways of accessing it.

### **1. Use of F12 key on the browser:**

```
This can be blocked using javascript key event listener. Use the below script to do accomplish it.

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){ 
       return false; 
    } 
});
```

### **2. Use of Right click**

```
You can block this using javascript or with just your html

<html oncontextmenu="return false">
</html>
or

$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

### **3. Use of other shortcuts involving Ctrl keys**

Include this snippet inside the body element.

oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"

### **4. By temporarily removing DOM when inspector is opened**

What the below snippet does is to detect when the debugger is opened, and removes the code and stores the code in a variable and and when the debugger is closed, it returns it.

```
var currentHtmlContent;

var element = new Image();

var elementWithHiddenContent = document.querySelector("#element-to-hide");

var innerHtml = elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML;   


element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {

    currentHtmlContent= "";

});

setInterval(function() {

    currentHtmlContent= innerHtml;

    console.log(element);

    console.clear(); 

    elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML = currentHtmlContent;

}, 1000);
```

Comment: This will disable *some* ways to open the console in *some* browsers, but there's nothing you can do to really prevent opening the console.